# Add items to IList with LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is my Model SigningAbsenceType

```
public class SigningAbsenceType
{
    public float YearAbsence { get; set; }
    public float SickAbsence { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add new item get from LINQ to every item in Model

```
var getType = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID).Select(t => t.Type).Distinct().ToArray();
IList<SigningAbsenceType> result = new List<SigningAbsenceType>();

for (int i = 0; i < getType.Length; i++)
{
    string t = getType[i];
    switch (getType[i])
    {
        case "A":
            var YearAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "A")
                .GroupBy(g => g.Type)
                .Select(h => new
                {
                    TotalHour = h.Sum(s => s.TotalHour)
                });
            break;
        case "S":
            var SickAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "S")
                .GroupBy(g => g.Type)
                .Select(h => new
                {
                    TotalHour = h.Sum(s => s.TotalHour)
                });
            break;
    }
}
return result;
```

How can I insert `YearAbsence` in LINQ into `IList<SigningAbsenceType> result`

I have tried `.ToList()` in LINQ and then add to result `result.Add(new SigningAbsenceType { YearAbsence = YearAbsence });`

But the error is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: float TotalHour>>' to 'float'`
Please help, I spent all day to solve this, but no result. Thanks very much

**Edit:** I have solved it

```
var getType = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID).Select(t => t.Type).Distinct().ToArray();
List<SigningAbsenceType> result = new List<SigningAbsenceType>();
float yA = 0;
float sickAbsence = 0; 
float harmfulAbsence = 0;
float unauthorizedAbsence = 0;
float personalAbsence = 0;
float compensatoryAbsence = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < getType.Length; i++)
{
    string t = getType[i];
    switch (getType[i])
    {
        case "A":
            yA = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "A").Sum(s => (s.TotalHour)/8);
            break;
        case "S":
            sickAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "S").Sum(s => (s.TotalHour) / 8);
            break;
        case "HA":
            harmfulAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "HA").Sum(s => (s.TotalHour) / 8);
            break;
        case "N":
            unauthorizedAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "N").Sum(s => (s.TotalHour) / 8);
            break;
        case "P":
            personalAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "P").Sum(s => (s.TotalHour) / 8);
            break;
        case "H":
            compensatoryAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "H").Sum(s => (s.TotalHour) / 8);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
result.Add(new SigningAbsenceType
{
    YearAbsence = yA,
    SickAbsence = sickAbsence,
    HarmfulAbsence = harmfulAbsence,
    CompensatoryAbsence = compensatoryAbsence,
    PersonalAbsence = personalAbsence,
    UnauthorizedAbsence = personalAbsence
});
return result;
```

Comment: Right, I want to sum the result, then insert into `IList<SigningAbsenceType> `

Comment: you must select all SigningAbsenceType properties
.Select(h => new SigningAbsenceType 
                {
                    TotalHour = h.Sum(s => s.TotalHour),
                    //other properties
                });
and AddRange to result

Comment: I got it, but I put them into switch and for, so when case runs, it add new SigningAbsenceType then, the older was lost, I have tried `case "A":
 var YearAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
  .Where(k => k.Type == "A")
  .GroupBy(g => g.Type)
  .Select(h => new SigningAbsenceType
  {
   YearAbsence = h.Sum(s => s.TotalHour)
  });
 break;` and after finish, it return 0

Answer (score 2):

**Note: updated after comment from Mrinal Kamboj**

So depending on the result of `getType[i]` you make an object of anonymous type, either a `YearAbsence`, or a `SickAbsence`, and you want to add this anonymous typed object to a `IList<SigningAbsenceType>`.

Alas, you can only add objects of class `SigningaAbsendType` to your list, after all, you defined it as a list of `SigningaAbsendType`.

The easiest method would be to declare `YearAbsence` and `SickAbsence` as objects of class `SigningaAbsendType`:

```
switch (getType[i])
{
    case "A":
        IEnumerable<SigningAbsenceType> fetchedSingingAbsences = oracleConn
            .SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
            .Where(k => k.Type == "A")
            .GroupBy(g => g.Type)
            .Select(h => new SigningAbsenceType
            {
                YearAbsence = h.Sum(s => s.TotalHour),
                SickAbsence = 0.0,
            })
            .ToList();

            // now you can add the fetched data to the list!
            foreach(SingingAbsence fetchedSigningAbsence in fetchedSingingAbsences)
            {
                result.AddRange(fetchedSigningAbsence);
            }
        break;

    case "S": // something similar
```

Another very similar method would be:

```
switch (getType[i])
{
    case "A":
        IEnumerable<float> fetchedYearAbsences = oracleConn
            .SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
            .Where(k => k.Type == "A")
            .GroupBy(g => g.Type)
            .Select(h => h.Sum(s => s.TotalHour));

        // add to the list:
        foreach (float fetchedYearAbsence in fetchedYearAbsences)
        {
             result.Add(new SigningAbsenceType
            {
                YearAbsence = fetchedYearAbsence,
                SickAbsence = 0.0f;
            });
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Result of a Select is an IEnumerable, which cannot be directly added to the another IEnumerable using Add, either you need to use AddRange or enumerate and Add every element of the Enumeration

Answer (score 1):

> But the error is Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous type: float TotalHour>>` to `float`

**This line tells the whole story, what happening is:**

1. Result of your query is `IEnumerable of a Anonymous Type`, which contains the float property `TotalHour` as property
2. You are trying to add `IEnumerable<<anonymous type: float TotalHour>>` to a value of type `float YearAbsence`, there's no compatibility between them to succeed, in the line `result.Add(new SigningAbsenceType { YearAbsence = YearAbsence });`, first `YearAbsence` is a float and assigned `YearAbsence` is an **IEnumerable of Anonymous type**

> **You need the following code**

```
foreach(var ya in YearAbsence)
{
  result.Add(new SigningAbsenceType { YearAbsence = ya });
}
```

It has to be added before `break;` in the `switch statement`, to add all the data generated post `linq query in the switch case` and I would recommend rename the `YearAbsence` enumeration to `YearAbsenceEnumeration` for clarity and no confusion, since you are generating the collection not a variable

Also remember there's no compatibility between the class:

```
public class SigningAbsenceType
{
    public float YearAbsence { get; set; }
    public float SickAbsence { get; set; }
}
```

and Anonymous type containing the name variable name `YearAbsence`, they are separate types, and can only be compared using primitive values

Answer (score 1):

Something like following should be fine:

```
var getType = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID).Select(t => t.Type).Distinct().ToArray();
IList<SigningAbsenceType> result = new List<SigningAbsenceType>();

var tempResult = getType.Select(t => {
    switch (t)
    {
        case "A":
            var YearAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "A")
                .GroupBy(g => g.Type)
                .Select(h => new
                {
                    TotalHour = h.Sum(s => s.TotalHour)
                }).Single();
            return new SigningAbsenceType(){ YearAbsence = YearAbsence.TotalHour };
        case "S":
            var SickAbsence = oracleConn.SelectAbsenceType(EmployeeID)
                .Where(k => k.Type == "S")
                .GroupBy(g => g.Type)
                .Select(h => new
                {
                    TotalHour = h.Sum(s => s.TotalHour)
                }).Singe();
            return new SigningAbsenceType(){ SickAbsence = SickAbsence.TotalHour };
    }
});
result.AddRange(tempResult);

return result;
```

Comment: This will not work, since `SickAbsence` is an `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>`, so `SickAbsence.TotalHour`, in the return statement will have issue

Comment: Yes, a dumb .Single() selector resolves the problem.

Comment: It will still fail, since `Single` works if there's only and absolutely 1 record, here you need `First`, still a bad idea since that to change the use case, Op intends to add all the records generated not just one record

Comment: @Mrinal Kamboj if you take a closer look at the code, you will see, that sets for every case ("S" / "A") has exactly one result as they are grouped by the type after applying where.